# SQL linked server local truncate - truncated linked data

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have had some unexpected results with the latest changes I have made to a stored procedure.

This procedure is supposed to truncate the local Database tables and refill from the Linked server.

The issue that I have seen is that somehow my Linked Server data has been truncated.

My sql is as follows

TRUNCATE TABLE Utility.dbo.tblSite

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Utility.dbo.tblSite ON

INSERT INTO Utility.dbo.tblSite(siteID, siteDataName, sqlServerName, isActive, baseLanguage, translationState, localInstance)

SELECT siteID, siteDataName, sqlServerName, isActive, baseLanguage, translationState, localInstance

FROM USS.Utility.dbo.tblSite

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Utility.dbo.tblSite OFF

update Utility.dbo.tblSite SET localInstance = Null

update Utility.dbo.tblSite SET localInstance = 1 WHERE sqlServerName = @@ServerName

Anyone have any idea why my USS data would be gone?
Do I need to specify the local database in front of the local table name so the truncate doesn't truncate the USS data?

Answer (score 0):

when you execute the `TRUNCATE TABLE Utility.dbo.tblSite` query, what is the current context? Since the database name, schema name and table name are the same then the server part effects the query.

Comment: Ok so if I am writing it on RSV and pulling from USS I need to specify the RSV for the local stuff so it isn't confused. Therefore; it should read Truncate Table RSV.Utility.dbo.tblSite?

Comment: yes, it shouldn't confused. Since you are not change anything (not update,delete,insert) at USS.Utility.dbo.tblSite, it mustn't be truncated. Problem should cause from anything else then mentioned here.

Comment: I have this fixed. I believe the data deletion must have come from running the procedure on the wrong server (ie the USS server instead of the RSV server). I have repopulated the data and re run the original procedure and everything works as expected. Moral of the issue -- be careful where you are connected to when running procedures designed for remote sites.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Good, Server.Database.shema.table is more secure as i told you.